# not all RAM recognised ~3.3 of 8GB

Tags: 64-bit, ram

- I recently installed some new RAM so that I have 8GB (4x2GB sticks).
- The Bios displays all four sticks, however Ubuntu only shows about 3.3GB available.
- Both the system details and info from terminal tell me that it is a 64bit OS

I am currently running memtest86 v5.01 - no errors so far but still on its first pass. My main issue is that it shows all four RAM sticks in the Memory SPD informations, however specifies 3371M of memory at the top.

[image: mem test image]

Any ideas why this is? Motherboard is compatible with 8GB RAM, as is CPU I believe.

Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems that your motherboard *doesn't* support more than 4g of memory.

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Answer (score 5):

It was a BIOS firmware problem, While the motherboard supported 8gb of RAM, the motherboard firmware (Dell) didn't.

After updating this it worked - for anyone reading who has a Dell Inspiron 530, with a foxconn g33m motherboard, I did have to use HPUSBDISK tool to create a DOS usb to flash the bios, as I received memory errors when I used Rufus

Answer (score 2):

This could be a hardware or a BIOS firmware problem.
 First if all I'd try to identify that the RAM modules are OK, by putting the new ones into slots 0-1 (or which definitely work). If that doesn't help, I would check the modules on another motherboard. If that doesn't help, I'd try to update the BIOS firmware. If that sounds too risky, try replacing the modules in the shop and get some new ones.